# programatically update-linked-named-range-of-excel-object-in-ms-word-2010

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have thoroughly read the above answer you posted in the link below.

[Programmatically Update Linked Named Range of excel object in MS Word (2007)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701266/programmatically-update-linked-named-range-of-excel-object-in-ms-word-2007)

I am facing issue while updating a shared drive path using the same above steps. My excel file is in a shared drive folder and I have tried putting in OLE objects manually, which I succeeded. While using a similar logic :

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("R1").Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject filename:=filename _
  & "!Range1", LinkToFile:=True"
```

it gives me the below error:

> Word is unable to create a link to the object you specified. Please
>   insert the object directly into your file without creating a link

I am not able to figure out why this error comes up. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Note: I am updating a new range as well as the file location and file name. I have verified range in excel file is valid.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since the link already exists, you shouldn't be using .AddOLEObject. You should instead be editing the filepath. For example:

```
Dim iShp As InlineShape
Const strPath As String = "New Path"
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  With iShp
    If Not .LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
      With .LinkFormat
        .SourceFullName = Replace(.SourceFullName, .SourcePath, strPath)
      End With
      With .Field
        .Code.Text = Replace(.Code.Text, "5 - EW_RA!R2C17", "6 - EW_RA!R2C17")
        .Update
      End With
    End If
  End With
Next
```

Comment: Macropod, thanks for the response, but I need to update the excel range as well.   ex:5 - EW_RA!R2C17 to 6 - EW_RA!R2C17. Hence I am breaking the link and recreating those using AddOLEObject.  I have put in the excel file in a shared drive and want to map the range in that excel file (one in shared drive). Please suggest

Comment: There is still no need to break the link - simply edit the field code. See my updated answer.

Comment: perfect thanks you so much, I will be trying it out. I would also like to know if there are any such method/property when I can update the excel range when I am using activedocument.shapes (not inline shapes). Please suggest

Comment: Thanks a lot Macropod, yes the inline shape works for me perfectly without the need to break any links

Comment: The simplest way to edit a linked Shape's range reference is to store it's positioning attributes, convert to InlineShape, update, convert to Shape, restore the positioning attributes.

Comment: hello macropod, is it possible to position an inline shape (msoLinkedOLEObjects) using vba. please help. I tried using the height and width property for inline shapes, not able to do so as the shapes disappear.

Comment: You cannot position an inlineshape the way you can a floating shape. Inlineshapes don't have positioning properties, which is why I said to get them for the shape objects *before* converting to inline...

Comment: when I try converting the shapes to inline shapes, the embedded object disappear,            i am trying the below thing:    If .Type = wdSelectionShape Then
               .ShapeRange(1).ConvertToInlineShape
             End If                                                                                                                      secondly, all the shapes refer to excel embedded object with OLE Links, but only few of the shapes are being recognized by .Type = wdSelectionShape. Is there any other way of getting hold off msoLinked shapes.

Answer (score 0):

For wrapped objects, with early binding:

```
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdShp As Word.Shape, wdRng As Word.Range, i As Long, Fmt As Long, StrID As String, StrNm As String
Dim vRel As Long, vPos As Single, hRel As Long, hPos As Single, Hght As Single, Wdth As Single
Const strPath As String = "New Path"
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\Target Document.docx", _
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=True)
  With wdDoc
    For i = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
      With .Shapes(i)
        If Not .LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
          Set wdRng = .Anchor: StrID = .OLEFormat.progID: StrNm = "\" & .LinkFormat.SourceName
          Fmt = .WrapFormat.Type: Hght = .Height: Wdth = .Width
          vRel = .RelativeVerticalPosition:   vPos = .Top
          hRel = .RelativeHorizontalPosition: hPos = .Left
          .Delete
        With wdRng
          .Fields.Add Range:=.Duplicate, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False, _
          Text:="LINK " & StrID & " " & Chr(34) & Replace(strPath & StrNm, "\", "\\") & Chr(34) & " " & _
            "6 - EW_RA!R2C17" & " \p"
          .End = .End + 1
          Set wdShp = .Fields(1).InlineShape.ConvertToShape
        End With
        With wdShp
          .WrapFormat.Type = Fmt: .Height = Hght: .Width = Wdth
          .RelativeVerticalPosition = vRel:   .Top = vPos
          .RelativeHorizontalPosition = hRel: .Left = hPos
          End With
        End If
      End With
    Next
    .Close True
  End With
  .Quit
End With
```

Comment: When I am running 
 Set iShp = oWordDoc.Shapes(d).ConvertToInlineShape from an excel, 
 instead of putting the sub in word document, it fails saying "Method ConvertToInlineShape of object Shape failed"

if I run the same program from a .docm file, following error appears: 
 The (.ConvertToShape) method sometimes make the shapes disappear. 
 sometimes it does show up but not able to restore positions. 
  the shapes which are in the document have 'wrap text' to be 'square' and after updating the links, the shapes become 'in line with text'.

Comment: Just to add to the above text, I am using past special --> then paste link --> OLE Links(1st option) while pasting the excel object, then in page layout, changing the wrap text to square to get desired position. I updating these links in the word document.

Comment: The code, as posted, works as is when run from Word. If being used in an automation context with early binding, all you'd need to do is specify iShp As Word.InlineShape and change ActiveDocument to oWordDoc.

Comment: below are the steps i followed and got the error: "Method ConvertToInlineShape of object Shape failed"   1. Copied a named range like : MS.GB_6.Reg from excel and did a paste special in word document either as picture or OLE links. Then seelct 'wrap text' to 'square' for positioning  2. I tried running the same code from excel with early binding and same code in word. it fails in .ConvertToInlineShape. Does this method have prerequisites or any other parameters which needs to be taken care off? MSDN site doesn't explain much

Comment: I just noticed one thing, these OLE objects are placed inside a table row. Can this cause an issue?                                                                                                
 When I try to debug ConvertToInlineShape , I noticed the link type changes to 'Excel.Sheet.12' from 'worksheet'. Update method changes to manual from Automatic.

Comment: The .ConvertToInlineShape method takes no arguments; it should run as-is, *provided* you specified iShp As Word.InlineShape.

Comment: Yes I did. As far as I have understood, it fails because the current shape is removed from shapes collection and tried getting included to inlineShapes collection which doesn't exist. Note: The method fails as the shape disappears, it's not able to return the inline shape even though the method has converted it. if I update the underlying link of the object the inline shape shows up.

Comment: Of course the shape 'disappears', as it's being converted to an inlineshape - as per my advice of 29 June. I am unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: Ok. Did you try using early binding? And how did u add shapes to word documents? I guess addition of shapes is making the difference. While pasting the shapes from excel, please try using paste special and select OLE links(1st option)   would it possible for you to add a check in the above code to validate if inlineShapes collection exists and then set the inlineShape(iShp).. in the above code, ishp is trying to be set where there is no inlineshapes collection. Please suggest

Comment: Yes, I used early binding. As for adding a shape object, I did so via Insert|Shape and set the wrapping to square. I commented-out the code relating to the link and its updating, as that's not relevant to your reported "Method ConvertToInlineShape of object Shape failed" error. The conversion to inline and back again works just fine.

Comment: yes if I add just shapes that it's working. I am trying to work one with links only. will you able to help me understand what kind off shapes gets added to word document when we copy a cell group from excel and use home | paste special | paste link | 1st option. Please guide – I am using the code format to map new named ranges from excel at run time and trying to position these shapes added to word document by converting it into inline shapes.I am using a master template which have the links & use it as baseline to produce other word documents

Comment: When you do that, you get a field representing the workbook content. To turn that into a shape object, you'd need to right-click and choose Format Object>Layout>Square; otherwise it wouldn't appear in the Shapes collection, and the ConvertToInlineShape code would never execute. I've posted a different approach for you to try. Do bear in mind, though, that none of this circumlocution would be required if you used a named range in the Excel workbook and simply applied that to whichever range is appropriate at the time. In that case, all you'd need code for is updating the path.

Comment: @ Macropod, thanks for all the help, I was able to sort the size issue as well.

Comment: I have few shapes in table cells (rows & columns), I see shapes size and position not getting restored after the new shapes are added in the table cells, will be able to advise if the above code should restore shape positions or do I need to add few more modifications to it. I mean is there something I need to do with table anchors? the sizes get a lot smaller